# How can I put image into polygon google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to put the image into custom size polygon like in the pic. How can I get this? I think this is a bad idea.
The colored area should be filled by any image instead of color.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzJpu.png

Comment: you can use an image overlay https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay

Comment: thanks, I already use it, but for rectangle area. For arbitrary polygons, this isn't worked.

Comment: you add an image .. if the image is not a rectangle but with transparent area should work ..

Comment: @scaisEdge, What I want ==> http://image.prntscr.com/image/c5f7c82c0b7b45479ea315d922f363f9.png

In your case, it's not a solution.

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to this question too +1 vote

Comment: Any luck on this?
I want to have tile image on top of polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Probably in your case **Custom Overlay** will be useful:
Check this [exmaple](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple)

**Code snippet:**

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132),
            new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608));

        // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
var srcImage = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/' +
            'javascript/examples/full/images/talkeetna.png';

        // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
        // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Artem, but this isn't worked for arbitrary polygons. Your example needs only two bounds and fills only rectangle area.

Comment: I'm using canvas with already drawn items inside.

What I want ==> http://image.prntscr.com/image/c5f7c82c0b7b45479ea315d922f363f9.png